# SVG file showing incomplete up in IE9 when embedded in other SVG

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

Trying to embed the file map.svg in another svg file using this code:

```
<svg version="1.2"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <image height="800" width="800" x="0" y="0"  xlink:href="map.svg"/>
</svg>
```

Works fine except in IE9 where parts of the map is missing. I can see the missing parts are defined in the last part of the rather big map.svg file.

If I directly open map.svg in IE9 there is no problem - only when it is embedded in another svg.

Is there a limit for the file size in IE9 or simply some kind of bug?

The file is here:

- http://byogtrafik.ramboll.dk/SandBox/QGIS_svg/Svg_in_svg.svg

EDIT: I can add that same problem occurs when embedding map.svg in html. Using "object" tag shows the complete map while using "img" tag shows map with missing parts in IE9. Take a look here (be patient - big svg file): http://byogtrafik.ramboll.dk/SandBox/QGIS_svg/Svg_in_object_and_img.html

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the root svg the width and height values:

```
<svg version="1.2" width="800" height="800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <image height="800" width="800" x="0" y="0"  xlink:href="map.svg"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank for the suggestions but it does not help - still something is missing.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics#Native_browser_support) IE9 only support basic SVG features. Your best shot would be to adjust the SVG file in such a way that it only uses basic features.  IE9 has not yet implemented the following set of features: SVG Animation (SMIL), Filters or Fonts. For more details see [Microsoft website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974378%28VS.85%29.aspx#_svg)